# Types of wire and applicability for guitar amps

Tags: amplifier, vacuum-tube

I'm working on a DIY project for a tube amp. Next step will be to buy the right components and then actually mount everything.

I have some experience with amplifier theory but have never built one. What kind of wire should I buy, and what is the applicability of these wires in relation to guitar amps?

1. Silicone Jacket Wire
2. Teflon jacket
3. Cloth jacket
4. PVC jacket

Comment: How many tubes are you planning to use (to get an idea of the filament current)

Comment: I'm planning to build fender 5e3 clone with Solid State rectifier. Are 4 tubes, two 12ax7 and two 6v6gt.

Comment: Nice. I'd go for the PVC wire - comes in lots of colors which is useful for tracing the circuit through. You may find this useful http://diyaudioprojects.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/tube-amplifier-wiring-color-code.html. It also has some good advice on construction - especially avoiding noise and earth loops. http://diyaudioprojects.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/design-and-construction-of-vacuum-tube.html If your using solid state rectifiers remember the high voltage comes up very quickly compared to the valve diode.

Comment: I saw some old projects, was common to use the Cloth jacket wire? There are advantages in use this kind of wires for the heaters?

Comment: Varnished fabric wire is the way to go for authenticity!!!

Comment: I would also suggest you a nice book : « building valve amplifiers » by Morgan Jones. It is not about valve amplifier theory but more on how to build one (tools and technics).

Comment: Ah yes, the old brown varnished cloth covered wire, I remember it well - might be authentic but it was horrible to work with. Perhaps you should also go for the old style rubber covered cable that tended to become brittle. Most of the heat in valve circuits comes from the valve heaters and the resistors - wires, provided the copper is of suitable thickness, should run cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teflon and silicon are resistant to heat which can be a big help when you solder twisted wires (ie heater circuit). Normal plastic might melt and make difficult to detect short circuits in twists. They are also more flexible than standard cable = easier to arrange your wires in the cab. 
I would avoid cloth wires which are a pain to bare.